# How can i turn on the CAPS LOCK of a specific usb keyboard when multiple keyboards are connected

Tags: java, keyboard, usb, toolkit

I have three usb keyboards attached to my computer. I want to activate the caps lock of a specific keyboard with the code below. The problem is that when i run the code, the caps lock of the three keyboards are turned on. Please help!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.comm.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TestKeys{

    public static void main(String ted[]){
        TestKeys c = new TestKeys();
        c.capslock(true);
    }

    public boolean capslock(boolean b){
        Toolkit tool = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        try{
            tool.setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK,b);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Caps lock, num lock, and scroll lock, are set globally on many BIOSes and operating systems.

Testing on Linux or on Windows, hitting the hardware keys for toggling caps lock, num lock, and scroll lock, toggles it on my second keyboard as well, so it's likely not possible to toggle it in software this way.

Note that you can't disable a keyboard or a port, do this, then reenable it as iit'll involve a ton of OS-specific hacks requiring JNI or devfs on Linux. When the ports are reenabled the reconnected keyboards will still take the lock status even if their lights indicate otherwise.

Comment: well too bad for me. Can't i disable the ports/hubs (through software) of the other two keyboards, then run the code? wouldn't disabling other ports block communication for those two keyboards?

Comment: @TedMad It depends on the OS. Most likely, not without a lot of low-level hacks. Besides, once the keyboards are reconnected, they'll take the caps lock status even if their lights don't take it.